# Branch locus of a projection

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm looking for a formula or quick trick for computing the branch locus of a hypersurface under projection.  My specific case:

Let $V\subset\mathbb{P}^3$ be a surface of degree $d$, $p\in\mathbb{P}^3$ (it's actually a node of $V$, if that's relevant), and I'm attempting to compute the branch locus of the projection $V\dashrightarrow \mathbb{P}^2$, which should be a plane curve.

Comment: Perhaps this could be helpful: http://books.google.com/books?id=WUDrpDGHHEsC&pg=PA31&lpg=PA31&dq=computing+the+branch+locus+V+of+P^2&source=bl&ots=PTrmd4B3uF&sig=4JADnIAEff_R2YoKAFeszP_Gbc0&hl=en&ei=XstETbPgGMGB8ga4htSZAg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CCMQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=computing%20the%20branch%20locus%20V%20of%20P%5E2&f=false